# Iteration vs recursion when dynamic lookup table is required

Tags: python, recursion, iteration, theory

I was wondering if iteration can be used when using a dynamic lookup table. Using recursion you can get all the necessary lookup table data from bottom to top.  I can't seem to grasp how we can achieve the same using iteration, without making a stack and ending up reimplementing the recursion.

For example, take my solution to Project Euler problem #14:

```
table = {1:1}

def collatz(n):
    if n in table:
        return table[n]
    elif n % 2:
        x = 1 + collatz(3*n + 1)
    else:
        x = 1 + collatz(n/2)
    table[n] = x
    return x

MAXc = 0

for i in xrange(1,1000000):
    temp = collatz(i)
    if temp > MAXc:
        MAXc = temp
        result = i

print result
```

How could we implement the same using iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An iterative algorithm which just counts the number of steps until reaching 1 is trivial. The problem is to also update the cache for all the intermediate values.

In this particular case there is an iterative algorithm which doesn't require an explicit stack. It uses two passes: the first counts the total number of steps, and the second updates the cache.

```
def next(n):
    if n % 2 != 0:
        return 3*n + 1
    else:
        return n/2

def collatz(n):
    count = 0
    i = n
    while i not in table:
        count += 1
        i = next(i)
    count += table[i]
    i = n
    while i not in table:
        table[i] = count
        count -= 1
        i = next(i)
    return table[n]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted! I wonder if there is any noticable difference in performance. Unless the iteration version is considerably faster, I don't see myself spending any time for the iterative implementation , taking into consideration that the recursive one is more straightforward and clear.

Comment: The iterative version is actually x1.5 slower on my machine. Removing the second pass (and only updating the cache for `table[n]`) brings it to about the same speed as the recursive version.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like (built code on fly, so sorry for any typos/bugs):

```
def collatz_generator(n):
    while n != 1:
        n = n & 1 and (3 * n + 1) or n / 2
        yield n

def add_sequence_to_table(n, table):
    table = table or {1:1}
    sequence = list(collatz_generator(n))
    reversed = list(enumerate(sequence))[::1]

    for len, num in reversed:
        if num in table:
            break
        table[n] = len + 1
    return table

def build_table(n):
    table = add_sequence_to_table(2)
    for n in xrange(3, n):
        table = add_sequence_to_table(n, table)

    return table
```

Without building table (typed on fly as wife wants me to get read):

```
def without_table(n):
    max_l, examined_numbers = 0, set()
    for x in xrange(2, n):
        reversed = list(enumerated(collatz_generator(x)))[::-1]
        for num, length in reversed:
            if num in examined_numbers:
                break

            examined_numbers.add(num)

            if num <= n:  # I think this was a problem requirement.
                max_l = max(max_l, length)
```

Doesn't this work?

Comment: This generates all the numbers and saves them in a list, which is equivalent to using a stack.

Comment: Yes. I was trying to get my recursion out of my first answer, which one thing you wanted, but really as you pointed out, not the important point.

Comment: I dropped the table. I did use a set to track examined numbers.

Comment: @tom I stuck in an array (`reversed`) but that can be decomposed into a generator as well. More to your theory question. Don't clever generators accomplish what you are looking for?

Comment: I didn't ask the question, Veritas did.

Comment: Stack as in the stack used on iterative depth search algorithms. I wasn't talking about the lookup table and I most certainly did not rule out all stacks. Just those that end up being like the ones created by the compiler for recursions.